# Migrating a Wubi install and Drivers, and data when the Wubi install is messed up

Tags: drivers, wubi, migration

I accidentally installed a non-functional video driver using the Jockey tool. That lead to me [only seeing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xocT5.jpg) on a reboot.

Which leads to my question: I read up on migrating my Wubi install, and I think it's time for me to format over XP (don't know why I hold on to it, since I have Windows 7 on that tower as well) and install Ubuntu on my second hard drive. I'm ready to copy my root.disk off of my computer, but I have a question with the migration process.

I borked something up bad on my Wubi install, so if I were to migrate my data from my Wubi install's virtual disk to my upcoming 12.04 install done the old-fashioned way, would my mistakes carry over to my new install? I don't think I'll lose anything of importance, but if I have the chance to recover that stuff, I'd like to take it.

Comment: If you migrate your data from your one installation to your other installation, the yes, your data will 'carry over'. Might not be obvious, but that's the whole point of your data migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's fix what happened on the other question.

You shouldn't just apt-get remove video drivers.  You should use `jockey-gtk` to switch between open drivers and closed drivers.
Press <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal.  Log in.

Update
`sudo apt-get update`
Get the latest packages
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
Make sure the driver switcher is installed
`sudo apt-get install jockey-common`
Update the driver database
`sudo jockey-text -u`
Get a list of all drivers available
`sudo jockey-text -m any -l`
Install one, just wait.  It takes a bit and there's no feedback on progress.
`sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia-current`
Make sure changes are written to disk
`sync`
Check to see that it's installed but not active yet
`sudo jockey-text -m any -l`
Restart
`sudo init 6`

You should now get to a GUI on boot.  You can use the additional drivers tool(jockey-gtk) to disable the binary driver if you want and it will enable the noveau driver for you.  Or you can just leave it if you don't want to mess with it once it's working.
[image]

Then the migration process should be straightforward.  It's documented [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F).
And yes, if you migrate it will carry almost all of your settings and almost all of your files.